# Parameter 0 of method bookIdResolver in com.rest.Application required a bean of type 'com.bookdata.DataService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am receiving this error and I am not sure why I thought I instantiated my beans correctly.

```
public class HttpDataService implements DataService  {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpDataService.class);

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   
    public HttpDataService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<DataResponse> getData(String bookId, Brand brand)  {}
```

And here is mu Application.class where I have

```
@Bean
    public BookIdResolver bookIdResolver(DataService dataService) {
        return new BookIdResolver(bookDataService);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you see the bean being created in the logs?

Comment: `HttpDataService` implements `DataService`, your `BookIdResolver` requires a `GDataService`. Typo or possible root cause?

Comment: @digitalbreed sorry it’s typo

Comment: Do you have a `@Bean` or similar stereotype annotation on `HttpDataService` then? How is it instantiated?

Comment: @digitalbreed I don’t

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - `@Bean` won't work as it's meant to be used on method level. Put a `@Service` on your `HttpDataService` class and it will be instantiated and will be available for wiring into your `bookIdResolver`.

Comment: @digitalbreed i tried that as well but again same error

Comment: Are there any earlier issues? Maybe `HttpDataService` cannot be created, too, because a bean of type `RestTemplate` can't be found?

Comment: @digitalbreed no earlier issues. Do you think I should create a Bean for RestTemplate in application.java class as well?

Comment: When you're using constructor injection (just like you're doing it with `BookIdResolver`), the constructor argument has to come from somewhere. Spring won't magically create a `RestTemplate` out of the blue. I am surprised that you're not seeing a corresponding error in the stacktrace and I am out of ideas then. I still suggest you post the full exception.

Comment: @user9347049 you actually need to create the bean for DataService that returns HttpDataService instance.

Comment: @Bean
    public DataService getDataService() {
        return new HttpDataService();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Bean for DataService

```
   @Bean 
   public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() { 
       return new RestTemplate(); 
   }

   @Bean
    public DataService getDataService() {
        return new HttpDataService(getRestTemplate());
    }
```

Comment: I added you code, but it searches for rest template

Comment: @user9347049  Please add a bean for RestTemplate as well.@Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }